# Prove a geometric sequence is bounded with common ratio $|r| \leq 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(V_n)$ be a geometric sequence with first term $a$ and with common ratio $r$. Prove that if $|r| ≤ 1$, then there exist real numbers $m$ and $M$ such that
$m ≤ V_n ≤ M$ for all $n ≥ 1$.

I know by intuition the sequence will be bounded but I'm unsure how to prove this mathematically.

Comment: For $r=1$ and $a\neq0$ you have that $V_n=na$. So, it wont' be bounded. They probably mean $|r|<1$. In that case $V_n=a+ar+ar^2+...+ar^n=a\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$. Then $|V_n|\leq |a|+|a||r|+...+|a||r|^n=|a|\frac{1-|r|^{n+1}}{1-|r|}\leq \frac{|a|}{1-|r|}$. Therefore you can take $m=-\frac{|a|}{1-|r|}$ and $M=\frac{|a|}{1-|r|}$.

Comment: I think the question means that any term $v_n$ is between $m$ and $M$ not that the sum is between $m$ and $M$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply $|V_n|=|a||r|^n\leq |a||r|$ so $-|a||r|\leq V_n \leq |a| |r|$? I'm assuming you really do mean a geometric sequence and not a geometric series.

Comment: I do mean a sequence yes but I don't understand why $|V_n|$ would help as it is just $|r|$ that is asked for, or am I interpreting the question incorrectly?

Comment: $|V_n|$ is helpful for several reasons. The one is that if $|V_n|\leq M$, then $-M\leq V_n \leq M$. The other is that we don't know the sign of $a$ or $r$. Using absolute values eliminates all the cases.

Comment: Okay I see now, so then $m$ is just $-|a||r|$ and $M$ is $|a||r|$, as you have said originally yes?

Comment: Yes, and those bounds are as good as you are going to get without breaking down into cases of $a$ and $r$.